Can you help me understand why an image in the header causes this browser exception exit code: 127 (command not found)?
I use browsershot to create PDF from views with browsershot.
and the header has a logo of the client who is creating the pdf, from a bitbucket link.
This works for some photos, but for others it causes an error 127
In cases where it does not generate, the image is sized 1959X576, 2560X751,
3298X956,
Those that generate are 702X403, 992X 198.
Does Browsershot have a limit on the image in the PDF?
logo.blade.php
<div style="position: absolute; padding-top: 1rem; color: black;
           font-style: italic; left: 9mm; top: 6mm;
           background: #F2EFE6; z-index: 999; display: flex; align-items: center;"
>
        @if(isset($logoUrl))
                <img
                        src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode($logoUrl) }}"
                        alt=""
                        style="height: 72px; margin-left: 1rem;"
                >
        @endif
</div>


    return Browsershot::html(self::generatePreview($client, $model)->render())
                 ->newHeadless()
                 ->noSandbox()
                 ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
                 ->format('A4')
                 ->showBackground()
                 ->timeout(120)
                 ->showBrowserHeaderAndFooter()
                 ->margins(27, 0, 13, 0)
                 ->footerHtml(
                     view(
                         'relatorio.footer',
     ['logo' => file_get_contents("img/logo-horizontal.png")]
                     )->render()
                 )
                 ->headerHtml(
     view('relatorio.components.logo', [
                         'logoUrl' => $logo
                     ])->render()
                 );


 "The command \"PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/var/www/project/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.cjs' '{\"url\":\"file:\\/\\/\\/tmp\\/324905047-0206139001717622055\\/index.html\",\"action\":\"pdf\",\"options\":{\"args\":[\"--no-sandbox\"],\"viewport\":{\"width\":800,\"height\":600},\"displayHeaderFooter\":true,\"newHeadless\":true,\"waitUntil\":\"networkidle0\",\"format\":\"A4\",\"timeout\":120000,\"margin\":{\"top\":\"27mm\",\"right\":\"0mm\",\"bottom\":\"13mm\",\"left\":\"0mm\"},\"footerTemplate\":\"<div style=\\\"position: absolute; padding-bottom: 1rem; color: black; ;\\n           font-style: italic; bottom: 20px; right: 15px; clear:both; z-index: 999999;\\n            display: flex; align-items: center;\\\"\\n>\\n    <span style=\\\"font-size: 16px; margin-right: 1.5mm;\\\">Powered by<\\/span>\\n alt=\\\"\\\"\\n                        style=\\\"height: 72px; margin-left: 1rem;\\\"\\n                >\\n        <\\/div>\\n\\n\\n\\n\",\"printBackground\":true}}'\" failed.\n\nExit Code: 127(Command not found)\n\nWorking directory: /var/www/project/public\n\nOutput:\n================\n\n\nError Output:\n================\n"`

I use puppeteer chrome to render directly and set the path to the direct node using a correct env constant:
composer.json:
      {
            "name": "laravel/laravel",
            "type": "project",
            "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
            "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
            "license": "MIT",
            "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
                "php": "^8.1",
                "spatie/browsershot": "^4.0",
 


package.json
    {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "dev": "vite",
            "build": "vite build"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "axios": "^1.1.2",
            "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
            "lodash": "^4.17.19",
            "postcss": "^8.1.14",
            "vite": "^4.0.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "@sentry/vue": "^7.40.0",
            "puppeteer": "^22.6.0"
        }
    }



It is necessary to manipulate the image with, I used intervention/image.
To reduce the size of images, never trust that the customer will not place a 3000x1000 photo in a 10cm space

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
